# Bounded positive function with first derivative strictly greater than second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a smooth real-valued function such that $0 < f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $f'(x) > f''(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Does such a function exist? I cannot come up with any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\arctan (ax) + {\pi\over 2} $ for $0<a<1.$ Then $0<f(x)\le \pi.$ Moreover $$f'(x)={a\over 1+a^2x^2},\ f''(x)=-{2a^3x\over (1+a^2x^2)^2}$$ For $x\ge 0$ we have $f'(x)>0\ge f''(x).$ For $x<0$ there holds $$f''(x)={-2ax\over 1+a^2x^2}{a^2\over 1+a^2x^2}\\ \le {a^2\over 1+a^2x^2} <{a\over 1+a^2x^2}=f'(x)$$

Comment: Thank you! I have asked [a slightly modified follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759003/bounded-positive-function-with-first-derivative-squared-strictly-greater-than-se), if you are interested.

Comment: Do not answer very low-quality questions, please.

Comment: You should give motivation or background explaining why this and the follow up question are interesting.